# Azure Devops - Create private task

Tags: azure-devops, agile, scrum

Is there a possibility to set the visibility of a task to private or a subset of the members, so that not all the ppl in the board can access the specific task?

i hope to raise acceptance of using the board

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [area paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) in Azure DevOps but I'm not sure it is a fit for this situation. Top level project admins will be able to see the extra area path exists however.